# Python list comprehension. Alternative/Better way to write this code?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here is an example i'm working with:

```
    >>> a = [('The','det'),('beautiful','adj')]
    >>> d = [y for (x,y) in a]
    >>> z = [x.lower() for (x,y) in a]
    >>> final=[]
    >>> final = zip(d,z)
    >>> final
    >>> [('det', 'the'), ('adj', 'beautiful')]
```

This is a good way to work with when working directly from the console. What if I had to run this from a .py file. I was wondering if there's an efficient/better way to re-write this, maybe using a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just generate the final output in one step:

```
final = [(y, x.lower()) for x, y in a]
```

or using better variable names to make it clearer what is put where:

```
final = [(tag, word.lower()) for word, tag in a]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [('The','det'),('beautiful','adj')]
>>> [(y, x.lower()) for x, y in a]
[('det', 'the'), ('adj', 'beautiful')]
```

Comment: Lovely! Thank you so much. I understand it well :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
[(i[1], i[0].lower()) for i in a]
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment instead of editing it. Anyways, I read it in an incorrect way. Thanks a lot. I understand it. :) I think your original answer was : final = [(a[1].lower(), a[0].lower()) for item in a], and my list of tuples was named as 'a'. That's why i got confused and asked if you were applying .lower() to a tuple. But thanks for the new version. It's clear.